# single digit month format

Tags: r, date, formatting

I have a date variable that includes month and year where the month is a single digit (e.g. this month/year is '62017', but October is '102017'). I need the final format to be '6/1/2017'.  I have tried using as.Date to convert but it will not work as %m requires two digits.

My workaround is to add a leading zero to dates that did not start with '102' (October), '112' (November), or '122' (December). I also have a few NA that I have to ignore. Code:

```
index <- substr(ll$Maturity.Date,1,3) != 102 & substr(ll$Maturity.Date,1,3) != 112 & substr(ll$Maturity.Date,1,3) != 122 & !is.na(ll$Maturity.Date)
ll$Maturity.Date[index] <- paste0(0,ll$Maturity.Date[index])
```

From here, I can convert to other formats as needed. However, I want to know if there is a better way to do this aside from hard coding as this code will break when using historical data in the 90's or data in the next century, both of which are future possibilities.

Comment: How are single digit days encoded? For June 1st, 2017, is it '6117'? Or '60117'?

Comment: there are no days encoded. The full value is myyyy e.g. '62017' for June or '112017' for November and '12017' for January.

Comment: You could test for the number of characters instead of the substring if `nchar(date.field) == 5` then paste the zero to the front.

Comment: Did you need the final date format to be `6/1/2017`? The answers below don't give you this format...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably easiest to use `sprintf` to pad the 0s. Here is one solution:

```
sprintf("%06.0f", as.numeric(temp))
[1] "062017" "102017"
```

Then combine this with `paste0` to add the day (1) and `as.Date` to get

```
as.Date(paste0(sprintf("%06.0f", as.numeric(temp)),"-1"), "%m%Y-%d")
[1] "2017-06-01" "2017-10-01"
```

**data**

```
temp <- c("62017", "102017")
```